# Adding line breaks using Survey.js

Tags: survey, surveyjs

I have a question that I want to have multiple paragraphs in the "title" field. What is the simplest way to add line breaks with survey.js?

Currently looking into using custom CSS to make "description" style match the "title" style , let me know if there's a simpler way!

Answer (score 1):

add script on your html head

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/1.6.4/showdown.min.js"></script>
```

and use `<br>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML and markdown in a question title. Here is the live sample - https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Library?id=survey-markdown-radiogroup&platform=jQuery&theme=modern